# Making columns of data lists in python

Tags: python, list

So I have a program, that reads through a bunch of files and appends the necessary data that I need. I need to now take those particular data and show them as a list. To be more specific, these are the parameters I have:

a = Source, b = luminosity, c = luminosity error, d = HST, e = XRS, f = gmag, g = z, and h = rh

I want to display this in a list, each defining a particular column. I just don't know where exactly I should insert the print statement among the various for loops I've done to do this.

I would appreciate any help! Here's the program (the main focus is in the for loops done and how they iterate through the data, and don't worry about indentations, the program so far works I just need to display the data appended in columns):

```
    import sys
    import os 
    import re
    import urllib
    import urllib2
    from os.path import basename
    import urlparse 
    import shutil


    base_dirname = '/projects/XRB_Web/apmanuel/499/'
    base_sourcefile = base_dirname + 'Sources.txt'

    try:
      file = open(base_sourcefile, 'r')
    except IOError:
      print 'Cannot open: '+base_sourcefile

    Source = []
    Finallist =  [] 
    ACS = [] 
    SRC = []


    for line in file: 
      data_line_check = (line.strip())
      if data_line_check: 

        line =  re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', line)
        point  = line.split('|')
        temp_source =  (point[0]).strip()
        if temp_source and len(point) == 3:
              Source = (point[0]).strip() 
              Source = re.sub(r'\s', '_', Source)
              print Source+"\n" 

        temp_finallist = (point[1]).strip()
        if temp_finallist: 
             Finallistaddress = (point[1]).strip()
             Finallistaddress = re.sub(r'\s', '_', Finallistaddress) 
             Luminositybase_dirname1 = '/projects/XRB_Web/apmanuel/499/Lists/' + Finallistaddress


     try:
       file2 = open(Luminositybase_dirname1, 'r')
     except IOError:
       print 'Cannot open: '+Luminositybase_dirname1

     source = []
     luminosity = []
     luminosityerr = []

     for line in file2: 
         pointy = line.split()
     a = int(pointy[0])
         b = float(pointy[5])
         c = float(pointy[6])

         source.append(a)
         luminosity.append(b)
         luminosityerr.append(c)

        temp_HST = (point[2]).strip()
        if temp_HST: 
          HSTaddress = (point[2]).strip()
          HSTaddress = re.sub(r'\s', '_', HSTaddress) 
          HSTbase_dirname2 = '/projects/XRB_Web/apmanuel/499/Lists/' + HSTaddress


     try:
       file3 = open(HSTbase_dirname2, 'r')
     except IOError:
       print 'Cannot open: '+HSTbase_dirname2

     HST = []

     for line in file3: 
     pointy2 = line.split()
     d = int(pointy2[0])
         HST.append(d)

      temp_XRS = (point[3]).strip()
      if temp_XRS: 
        XRSaddress = (point[3]).strip()
        XRSaddress =re.sub(r'\s', '_', XRSaddress) 
        XRSbase_dirname3 = '/projects/XRB_Web/apmanuel/499/Lists/' + XRSaddress


     try:
       file4 = open(XRSbase_dirname3, 'r')
     except IOError:
       print 'Cannot open: '+XRSbase_dirname3

     XRS = []

     for line in file4: 
     pointy3 = line.split() 
     e = int(pointy3[0])
         XRS.append(e)

    temp_others = (point[4]).strip()
    if temp_others: 
       othersaddress = (point[4]).strip()
       othersaddress =re.sub(r'\s', '_', othersaddress) 
       othersbase_dirname4 = '/projects/XRB_Web/apmanuel/499/Lists/' + othersaddress

     try:
       file5 = open(othersbase_dirname4, 'r')
     except IOError:
       print 'Cannot open: '+othersbase_dirname4

     gmag = []
     z = []
     rh = []

     for line in file5: 
     pointy4 = line.split()
     f = float(pointy4[3])
         g = float(pointy4[5])
         h = float(pointy4[7])
         rh.append(f)
         gmag.append(g)
         z.append(h)
```

Comment: Seems an incredibly backwards way to name your variables as `a, b, c, e, f, g ...` and then have to explicitly name them for us. Why not just use variable names like `source, luminosity, luminosity_error, hst, xrs ...`?

Comment: Sorry, I was just pointing things out in the general layout of the problem. So far I've thought of taking the for loops inside a def() statement and then printing the loop, but it only gives me a mess.

Comment: Have you considered using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)? It will probably simplify your file-scanning code a lot and let you focus on the data analysis instead. In particular, look at the documentation on reading text files using [IO Tools](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files).

Answer (score 0):

this function will return columns for a list of rows. note that this requires the lists to all have an element in the column you are trying to access, though it would be relatively simple to change this if you need it.

```
def getcolumn(matrix,index):        #index specifies which column of the matrix you want. note that like all other list indexes, this starts from 0, not one.
    column = []
    for row in matrix:
        column.append(row[index])
    return column
```